# Retrieve information in JSONPath SoapUI

Tags: arrays, json, soapui, jsonpath

I have a JSON response in SoapUI that looks like this:

```
{
  "civilite" : "1" ,
  "nom" : "Fitz",
  "prenom" : "Quinn",
  "dateN" : "07/10/1953"
}
```

But I want to use JsonPath to retrieve only a part of this data, so I could have something like this:

```
{
  "nom" : "Fitz",
  "prenom" : "Quinn"
}
```

Is there a way to apply a JsonPath expression to retrieve this information?

Comment: You mean to say that retrieve some data from first step and set it to next request?

Comment: Yes, I got that response and for the next request I only need those two parameters

Comment: Was that the entire response? just part of it?

Comment: Yes, the entire. I'm using Groovy Script and then I wrote something like "testRunner.testCase.testSteps["creationCompte"].getProperty("Response").getValue()"

Comment: I was asking if you could post the raw response? Need full response, you could replace dummy values.

Comment: Ok thank you for confirming. Ignore earlier message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first request step, add `Script Assertion` and use below script. The script extract the `nom` and `prenom` values and set them at test case level custom properties with given property names. With `Script Assertion`, an additional `Groovy Script` test step can be avoided.

Then in the next test step, use property expansion, so that those values will be replaced automatically with actual values by soapui.

**Script Assertion:**

```
//Check if the response is non empty or null
assert context.response

//Parse Json
def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
log.info "Nom: ${​parsedJson.nom}"
log.info "Prenom: ${parsedJson.prenom​}"

//assert if nom and prenom are not empty
assert parsedJson.nom, "nom is null or empty in the response"
assert parsedJson.prenom, "prenom is null or empty in the response"

//Set the retrieved values at test case level properties NOM, PRENOM
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('NOM', parsedJson.nom as String)
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('PRENOM', parsedJson.prenom as String)
```

Change 2nd step request content as below with **Property Expansion**

```
{
  "nom" : "${#TestCase#NOM}",
  "prenom" : "${#TestCase#PRENOM}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot! I just had to change the "log.info" part, it worked for me without the "{}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
input = {
  "civilite" : "1" ,
  "nom" : "Fitz",
  "prenom" : "Quinn",
  "dateN" : "07/10/1953"
}

output ={};

 input.reduce(function (result, currentObject) {
            output = {
                    nom: currentObject.nom,
                    prenom: currentObject.prenom
                };

                return output;
            }, output);
```